# Does P.M.I. stand for point wise mutual information or something else in the context of algorithm analysis?

Tags: algorithms

The following comes from Exercise 2.3-3 of “Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition by CLRS”

[image]

Here is [a solution](https://walkccc.me/CLRS/Chap02/2.3/) to that exercise

[image]

that solution says at the end “By P.M.I., T(n)=n lg n, when n is an exact power of 2”, what does P.M.I. mean in this context?

Comment: I think that P. M. I. here means *Principle of Mathematical Induction*, since the solution uses mathematical induction.

Comment: I believe the comment by @Russel is correct, nothing about mutual information in that proof.